# Проблема с юниттестами

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты

Подскажите, почему тестирование не срабатывает? Выдает ошибку `<__main__.VectorCount object at 0x02DADE90> != <__main__.VectorCount object at 0x02DADE10>`

```
import unittest

from math import sqrt, acos, degrees
import unittest


class VectorCount(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return VectorCount(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y, self.z + other.z)


class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        a = VectorCount(2, 3, 4)
        b = VectorCount(5, 4, 1)
        c = a + b
        z = VectorCount(7.0, 7.0, 5.0)
        self.assertEqual(c, z)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Так вы же сравниваете свой тип данных для которого отсутствует операция сравнения, поэтому сравниваются ссылки, которые у разных объектов разные.
Необходимо реализовать операцию сравнения, например так:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y and self.z == other.z
```